# ubuntu 14.04 / 64 bit stucks while using it

Tags: upgrade

newbie here!!!
so guys I’m running Ubuntu 14.04 and everything was perfect before i begun to get stuck while using it, several times, the systems just stop and nothing is working!every time i need to press the power off button to shutdown the systems and power it on again, and I’m losing a lot of things can any one tell me what to do??? thanks in advance
when it stuck it looks like this:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see this at times too, but I usually don't restart the system, rather I just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-F6</kbd> and move to the command line. Without doing a thing there, I return to `unity desktop` by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. This in most cases fixes the hang issue, and gets things working normal again.

If its still stuck its wiser to restart just `unity` and not the entire system. When stuck, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, enter credentials and do:

```
sudo service lightdm restart.
```

This has saved me a couple of times. Though in the second method you anyways end up losing all opened docs and stuff, but at least you save yourself from rebooting the system.